# Non Volatile Alternate to using INDIRECT() for File name specified in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a non volatile way of specifying reference to a cell in another workbook from a manually entered file path that is specified in a cell. I need a non volatile way as I will need to reference cells using this method may thousands of times which will slow excel to a halt otherwise. I currently using this formula

```
INDIRECT("'["&Sheet1!$D$6&Sheet1!$H$6&"]"&"Page1"&"'!"&"A1"))
```

Cell D6 on sheet1 has the file name typed in it eg "Book2"

Cell H6 on sheet1 has the file extension typed in it eg ".xls"

This then references cell A1 as: '[Book2.xls]Page1'!A1

This is what I am wanting to achieve but using a non volatile method, I know I am going to have to use VBA so I would need a function to work as follows

-reference the two cell D6 and H6 for the file name and file extension

-the file path needs to always be the current directory as the location can change

So I can use the function like this when I want to refer a cell on my work book which the file name is in cells D6 and H6

```
FILE(Page1!A1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no native function within VBA that can return a cell value from a closed workbook.  However, in the forerunner of VBA, a language called XLM there is a suite of functions called by `ExecuteExcel4Macro` that have not been upgraded for VBA but which are backwards compatible.  This suggestion uses one of these `Application` calls.  It will no doubt need further refining to meet your needs.

I used [this article by John Walkenbach](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/) as the basis for this suggestion.

You may also find [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193589%28v=office.15%29.aspx) helpful as a starting point for further research.

```
Sub readClosed()
Dim fName As String, fExt As String, fDir As String
Dim destCell As Range

'closed file info
fName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 4).Value   'Sheet1!D6
fExt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 8).Value    'Sheet1!H6
fDir = CurDir() & "\"   'currently selected folder

'destination cell for result returned
Set destCell = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2)

'create string for function call
arg = "'" & fDir & "[" & fName & fExt & "]" & "Page1" & "'!" & _
      Range("A1").Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)

'call function
destCell = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

End Sub
```

It is also possible to ADO to achieve what you require but it may be a bit more lengthy.

**EDIT FOR USING OPEN FILE**

This function will check if the 'target' file is open and if not open it.  Depending on the function argument you supply, it will close the file or not.  The function as written requires six arguments to give you maximum flexibility.  You can of course adjust these to suit.  The 'current working folder' may need to be specified.  If the target file is open but has not yet been saved then the current working folder will default to the 'users' folder, which may be problematic.  For my example I have explicitly specified the 'working directory' in cell J6 and the function return value to be written back to cell A6.

I have also given an example of the calling Sub with details allowing you to tweak/understand the various 'settings'.

**Function**

```
Function readValue(ByVal fDir As String, _
                   ByVal fName As String, _
                   ByVal fExt As String, _
                   ByVal fSheet As String, _
                   ByVal fCell As String, _
                   ByVal fClose As Boolean) As Variant

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbOpen As Boolean

wbOpen = False
readValue = ""

    'is tgtWb already open
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name = fName & fExt Then
            wbOpen = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb

    'if not open it
    If Not wbOpen Then
        If Dir(fDir & fName & fExt) <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open filename:=fDir & fName & fExt
        Else
            MsgBox "Workbook not found."
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

'does worksheet exist
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Workbooks(fName & fExt).Sheets(fSheet)
On Error GoTo 0
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        readValue = Workbooks(fName & fExt).Sheets(fSheet).Range(fCell).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet not found."
    End If

'close target workbook if required
    If fClose Then
        Workbooks(fName & fExt).Close savechanges:=False
    End If

End Function
```

**Calling Sub example**

```
Sub test()
'Retrieve a single cell value from another workbook
'Place value in ThisWorkbook.wkgSht.destCell
'Other workbook can be open or closed
'Other workbook can be left open or closed by function

Dim fDi As String, fNa As String, fEx As String
Dim fSh As String, fCe As String
Dim wkgSht As String, destCell As String
Dim closeFile As Boolean

'destination cell for returned value, in ThisWorkbook
destCell = "A6"
'sheet containing target file details and destination cell, in ThisWorkbook
wkgSht = "Sheet1"

'target file info/arguments for function call
fCe = "A1"
fSh = "Page1"
fNa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wkgSht).Cells(6, 4).Value   'Sheet1!D6
fEx = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wkgSht).Cells(6, 8).Value    'Sheet1!H6
'fDi = CurDir() & "\"   'currently selected folder
fDi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wkgSht).Cells(6, 10).Value    'Sheet1!J6  'for testing

'call function and place returned value in destCell
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wkgSht).Range(destCell).Value = readValue(fDi, fNa, fEx, fSh, fCe, False)

End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**

I have used [this article](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/) as a reference for volatility.  I don't think my suggestion breaches any of the points made there (other than perhaps opening a workbook?) although due to my own incomplete knowledge, I wouldn't presume this to be definitive.

Comment: I've no issues if I need to have the file open first what I'm referencing if that makes life easier, what suggestion would you have if I do it that way?

Comment: Is this option non-volatile? Could you provide a reference to documentation for this? +1 for the useful info!

Comment: @sancho.s see also Edit 2

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to flag a user-defined function as volatile otherwise it is non-volatile.

This would be done with the Application.Volatile method in the user-defined function.